# Designing apparently multiple level nested actions and batching them

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

The setup of a slice of my app is something like this:

An appliance gets its data from one or several dataSources. A user interacts with one or more appliances. Now, the dataSources provides realtime data, which is fetched per appliance at a regular interval and then displayed. So the structure can be displayed something as:

```
User <----->  (Appliance1, Appliance2) <------> ((DataSource1, DataSource2), (DataSource1, DataSource3, DataSource4))
```

Note that the data sources may overlap. So its a two-tier-ish, overlapping design.

Currently, the actions are set up as follows (code is not 100% syntactically true - just a design question):

```
ComponentContainer {
    ...

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setInterval(() => {
            this.props.appliances.forEach(appliance => dispatch(fetchApplianceRealtime(appliance))
        }, 4000))
    }
}


// in src/actions/appliance.js
fetchApplianceRealtime(appliance) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        fetchApplianceRealtimeInit(appliance) // I may want to toggle a flag here

        const promises = appliance.dataSources.map(ds => return dispatch(fetchDataSourceRealtime(ds)))
        Promise
            .all(promises)
            .then(() => {
                dispatch(fetchApplianceRealtimeDone(appliance))
            })
            .catch(() => {
                dispatch(fetchApplianceRealtimeFail(appliance))
            })
    }
}


// in src/actions/data-source.js
fetchDataSourceRealtime(ds) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        // No need for Init() action as data sources dont need their own fetching flag or something.
        return fetch(...)
            .then(resp => {
                // normalize
                return dispatch(fetchDataSourceRealtimeDone(ds, entities)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return dispatch(fetchDataSourceRealtimeFail(ds, error)
            })
    }
}
```

So, is this a decent design? I strongly feel I am missing out on some feature here. Is the nesting of actions the best way, given the scenario? Can any other improvements be made here?

UPDATE:
One problem I am facing here is propagating a fetch error in one or more `fetchDataSourceRealtime` calls up in `fetchApplianceRealtime`.

Now I have a feeling I am I am just looking at this problem from a wrong perspective.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Is something not working? If you want to propagate the error, throw it again in the `catch` handler after dispatching, and always let the caller handle it.

Comment: You're doing pretty much what the following example is doing: https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/middleware/api.js so I'd say you're ok. Although that example uses a nice mechanism that defines the action chain (what to do on failure / success) right in the initial action and uses the API middleware as a sort of preprocessor.

Comment: @DanAbramov The design as it is works, but I am not too sure of the nesting of the async actions, and had a feeling that there is a better solution I have missed. So I want some suggestions in that direction.

Comment: @DanAbramov or may be I simply haven't been able to warp my mind around the concept completely.

Comment: @MattW. I see. I agree that it sure handles the redundancies very elegantly, but I planned to move on to that stage after I was sure of all my actions and reducers and state.